# puppet error: Could not find class apt

Tags: vagrant, puppet, apt, librarian

When issuing the vagrant up command, I get an error like this:

```
Could not find class apt for precise64.inglewood.ca.us at at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/default.pp:19 on node precise64.inglewood.ca.us`
```

Line 19 of default.pp contains:

```
include apt
```

Any ideas?

Im on Windows 8+Cygwin+ruby2.0

Comment: you need to get the `apt` puppet module. take a look at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html. Look for the `module_path` option.

Comment: As Petey T said, it looks like you're missing a custom module.

Can you post your Vagrantfile or repo with your code in? You might need to run a pre-requisite to get the Puppetlabs apt module mirrored onto your Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 5):

what''s the puppet module list says does this include apt module ?

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-apt
```